# What are abjurations and how do they work?

Tags: warhammer-40k

So... I got into WH40k and I've noticed something called 'abjurations' being described a lot in the lore. Can anyone explain these daemon repelling ward-generating magical words to me? I can't find anything in giving a concrete answer as to what these are.

Comment: Which WH40K roleplaying game is this question about?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, the question was general lore. I found the answer elsewhere, and it's... complicated.

Comment: I can imagine; it’s a setting with decades of development. Anyway, why I asked: We only handle RPG related questions. Since WH40k is a majority wargaming setting, questions about it have to have an overt RPG angle, else it’s outside of our topic of expertise.